# Multiple ClassCleanup Attributes per Test Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, integration-testing, mstest

**Situation**: Some of my integration test classes share a common approach to setup scenarios in a database hence I provide an abstract base class. It also takes care of a full data cleanup at the end after all tests ran:

```
public abstract class IntegrationTests
{
    ...
    protected static void Cleanup() { ... }
}
```

My inherited classes are required to call the base method to ensure that my base cleanup code runs:

```
[TestClass]
public class FooIntegrationTests : IntegrationTests
{
    ...

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void FooCleanup()
    {
        ...
        Cleanup();
    }
}
```

**Issue**: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx) "[o]nly one method in an class may be decorated with [the ClassCleanup] attribute" so I cannot decorate the `Cleanup` method from the base class and even if I did the method wouldn't get get called.

**Question**: I want a solution which

- always runs the `Cleanup` method from the base class without implementing anything in the inherited classes, *and*
- always runs a custom cleanup method from the inheriting test class if there is any.

I dislike to force the inheriting test class to explicitly call the base class as I have to remember to implement it. I preferred a more elegant yet simple(!) technique. Any ideas?

**Note**: Providing a singleton for my base functionality which is to be shared by all test classes doesn't work because I run my tests on multiple test agents in parallel which all are connected to the same database instance.

Comment: The `ClassCleanup` attribute can only be assigned to static methods. `virtual` and `override` keywords can only be used on instance methods.

Comment: Ah, right, I was thinking of the usual setup/teardowns.  Apologies.

Comment: A static method/class breaks the normal inheritance rules.  So no, I'm not certain there's much you can do here other than call Cleanup from your inheriting class.

Answer (score 0):

Basing my answer from the comments, where calling ClassCleanup is no longer in play.

I do this all the time in my work. All you have to do is to peg the base class as a testclass too, and "spend" your cleanup and teardown attributes there. If you need cleanup/teardown in your derived class, just make a virtual method that you can ovveride whenever you need them:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeEach() {
        // Stuff that should happen before each unit test

        BaseTestInitialize();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void AfterEach(){
        // Stuff that should happen after each unit test

        BaseTestCleanup();
    }

    public virtual void BaseTestInitialize() { }
    public virtual void BaseTestCleanup() { }
}
```

With this construct, all you have to do in your integration test is to override the BaseTestCleanup() as such:

```
[TestClass]
public class DerivedTestClass : BaseIngetrationTest
{
    public override void BaseTestCleanup()
    {
        // Derived cleanup
        base.BaseTestCleanup();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeMethod_SomeCriteria_SomeResult()
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act

        // Assert
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea if you need initialization and/or cleanup for every test. Unfortunately, this approach causes serious performance problems for *integration* tests: setting up and cleaning data scenarios is intense and running this tens or hundreds of times per class is too expensive.

Comment: I typically flag my integrations tests with a testcategory, so they only run at night and of course whenever someone is working with them. I never do tests that do any kind of IO (including disk) in my Continuous Integration.

Comment: We do the same: integration tests run only twice a day plus on request. However, a data setup can cost many seconds - test suites would run for hours we had to recreate and delete scenarios for every single tests.

Comment: I agree, it depends largely on the product though. I'm currently running around 6000 unit tests in around 14 seconds. The integration test run takes around 20 minutes. ALL of them use a base class initializer.